# Ordering mptt tree using a field

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

This is the original category model:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
```

Then I needed to order the category, so I altered it like the following:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    order = models.SmallIntegerField() <<<<<<<<<
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['order'] <<<<<<<<<
```

And I changed the Django admin declaration from:

```
admin.site.register(Category, MPTTModelAdmin)
```

To:

```
class CategoryAdmin(MPTTModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'order')
    list_editable = ('order',)


admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

Then everything fall apart after making a few edits from the admin control panel. I can't describe exactly what happened but it seems the `lft`, `rght`, `level` and `parent_id` where messed up by these changes.

Am I using `order_insertion_by` in the wrong context? Is it for something else? I tried to search the docs but didn't get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem. The problem is not in the package django-mptt, and in the framework Django, more precisely in the admin. Perhaps this is due to several administrators working simultaneously. While only one solution - to **abandon the** `list_editable` **in admin class** or write a script with the same field `order` for Ajax.

In order to restore the tree, use [`rebuld`](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/mptt.managers.html?highlight=rebuild#mptt.managers.TreeManager.rebuild) method: `Category.tree.rebuild()`